# Haskell: How to show all elements in impair and pair indexes from a list?

Tags: list, haskell, indexing

**It will need to get the next imput and output:**

```
pospair [1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11]
        [1, 9, 5, 1]

posimpair [1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11]
          [3, 2, 7, 11]
```

This is the way to obtain the element on the specified index:

```
show_in_index::Ord a=>[a]->Int->a
show_in_index l n = l!!n
```

It shows a result like this:

```
*Main> show_in_index [1,4,2,7,9] 3
7
```

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried so far ? We can then help you better.

Comment: All I know so far is that this is the way to find an element in an specific position but I don't know how to show all elements in the impair positions or in the pair positions:                                     `show_in_index::Ord a=>[a]->Int->a
show_in_index l n = l!!n`

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to do this is using recursion:

```
pospair :: [a] -> [a]
pospair xs = aux xs [] True
    where
      aux [] acc _ = acc
      aux (y:ys) acc True = aux ys (acc ++ [y]) False
      aux (y:ys) acc False = aux ys acc True
```

Note how I use `True` or `False` value to keep track of what value to eliminate. If it's False, I don't include the value in `acc` (accumulator). If it's `True`, I include the value. Using the same idea, you can implement `posimpair`.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the function for indexing

For pospair the following works:

```
map ([1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11] !! ) [0,2..length [1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11]-1]
```

For posimpair we only have to change the second list that is the one that holds the indexing numbers, previously we had the series of pairs and now we want the series of impairs, so instead of having 0,2,.. until the length of the list -1 we have to do it with 1,3,..until the length of the list-1.

```
map ([1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11] !! ) [1,3..length [1, 3, 9, 2, 5, 7, 1, 11]-1]
```

The general implementation is

pospairs = map (list !!) [0,2..length list - 1]

posimpairs = map (list !!) [1,3..length list - 1]

I tested your example and works.